# Has AWS changed how Security groups work recently?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We recently had an EC2 machine with a Wireguard VPN stop working in the middle of the night in the last two days.  After troubleshooting it, the problem seemed that incoming UDP packets were not reaching the machine.  I edited the security group to allow incoming UDP packets and everything started working again.

Initially, I thought someone had changed the security group, but cloudtrail shows my edit as the only action in the last 90 days.  That must mean there is either a bug, or SG behavior changed in the last two days to not allow related packets back in on a connection.

The answer here by Michael is what I would assume to be truth:
[AWS Security Group show 'UDP Port open' while it should deny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699113/aws-security-group-show-udp-port-open-while-it-should-deny)

Am I mistaken?  Is there something else I should consider?

EDIT 1: Some clarifications

The EC2 machine is connecting via wireguard to a machine in a data center.  Both ends of the connection run wireguard in a docker container.

My troubleshooting steps were roughly the following (please ignore exact syntax since netcat varies across linux distributions)

On the EC2 machine I ran the following:

```
echo help | nc -u -l 5000
```

On the data center machine I ran the following:

```
nc -u ec2.example.com 5000
```

I found this didn't work until I added the UDP rule to the SG.  Once I did, the tcpdump I was running in another window exploded with traffic.

Comment: A change of this magnitude seems .. unlikely.  AWS is rather risk adverse to such a massive change without a clear and lengthy migration strategy.  I'd be more inclined to think a security group was added or removed from the instance that changed the overall policy for UDP traffic.

Comment: I agree, I would have expected to see other people complaining.  I am leaning towards bug that might disappear if I delete the EC2 instance and recreate it

Answer (score 0):

A more likely explanation is that Wireguard changed their logic whereby the response comes from a different server than the one which received the original request.  You can enable [VPC Flow Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html) to see whether this is what is going on.

Comment: it is a single server in a data center under out control.  Let me edit my question to include a few things I did to troubleshoot